# Which points are limit points and which are isolated points?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $S = \left\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} | \ ||x||_{2} \lt 1 \right\}$ $\cup$ $ \left\{ x = (\zeta_{1},...,\zeta_{N})^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{N} \ | \ ||x||_{2} = 1, \ \zeta_{1} \gt 0 \right\}$

Which points of $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ are limit points of S? Does S have any isolated points?

I understand what limit points and isolated points are but I'm struggling to apply the definitions to answer this question. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case $N=3$. Then $S$ is the open unit ball with the upper right octagonrant(if i say it right) of the unti sphere. Then the accumulation points of $S$(not the limit points-this stands for sequences) is the whole closed unit ball. This also means that $S$ has not any isolated points,because $S$ has more accumulation points that it's own points.

Comment: I don't think I understand, could you expand on your answer a little? Why is it the octagonrant of the unit sphere? And why are they accumulation points, not limit points?

Comment: About limit points. By definition,$x$ is an accumulation point of $A$ iff there is a sequence $(x_n)\subset A,x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$:$x_n\to x$. Now ,$x$ is a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)$ iff there is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ that converges to $x$.  About the octagonrant,imagine a sphere $N=3$ and get three axons $x,y,z$ with start at $0$, and see that $\left\{ x = (\zeta_{1},...,\zeta_{N})^{T} \in \mathbb{R}^{N} \ | \ ||x||_{2} = 1, \ \zeta_{1} \gt 0 \right\}$ is an actagonrant.

Comment: OK so why is this an accumulation point and not a limit point exactly?

Comment: And could you explain in more detail why exactly it is the closed unit ball?

Comment: You can also use the limit points definition for sets if for example you have a family of sets $(A_n):A_1\supset A_2\supset ...$ and see if the have an accumulation point let's say $A$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the accumulation points consist of the whole closed unit ball?

Comment: Yes. The accumulation points of the open unit ball is all the closed unit ball,because if we name $O$ the open unit ball then each element of $O$ is an accumulation point of $O$(i think you can see this why) and each point of the unit sphere,name it $U$ is an accumulation point of $O$,because if we take a $x\in U$ then $x\in O'<=>\forall G:x\in G$,$G$ open ,we have that $G\cap O\neq \emptyset$. Now some of the $G$'s look like $Δ(x,ε)$(an open disk) (other are union of these forms) and so it easy to see that $Δ(x,ε)\cap O\neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Why is each element of O an accumulation point of O?

Comment: Because you can build a sequence $x_n$ :$x_n\neq x$ for every $x\in O$ :$x_n\to x$. You can build this (one thought) by finding the distance between an element $a\in O$ and $x$ and get a partition of the path from $a$ to $x$ that has lenght the distance of $|x-a|$,and between each part of the partition you can select a point that will build your sequence.

Comment: Could you put that into the form of a formal solution? I kind of understand what you're saying but I'm not sure how to construct a proper answer...